# Check if vector is uninitialised at a certain position

Tags: c++

This seems like a really basic thing to do, but anyway I couldn't manage to find a solution to it so far, because I always find only questions that are asking how to check if the vector is actually empty, which is not what I want to check for.
Consider this code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Atom {
    int x,y;
    int pol;
};

int main() {
    vector<vector<Atom>> vec=vector<vector<Atom>>(5,vector<Atom>(5));
    cout<<(vec[0][0]==nullptr); // this line doesn't compile, because the vector doesn't hold pointers.
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to declare a vector of vectors of objects of a custom type. At the beginning of the Programm I will initialise the vector so that it has a specific size, but without assigning an actual object to it. Now I want to be able to check if I already assigned an object to a specific position of the vector. I would've liked to use something like `vec==nullptr` but this doesn't work, because the objects in the vector aren't pointers. Unfortunately I can't just change the structs standard constructor to put some indicator value that I can check for like `Atom.pol==-2`, because the class is created by ROS messages. Any other suggestions on how to check if I already assigned an object?

EDIT: pol will always be either -1 or 1 after I assigned an object. So is it safe to check `Atom.pol==0`? When I tried to do this on ideone.com it always worked, but I assume that it's not guaranteed to be 0, right?!

Comment: In your use case, it is perfectly safe to check `Atom.pol == 0` but I would rather declare `pol` as enum class type with UNKNOWN value equal to 0.

Comment: @NutCracker It is? In which cases would it NOT be safe then? (just because this is obviously not my actual code, but just something small to demonstrate my issue)

Comment: @NutCracker you better get rid of bad habit of all uppercase CONSTANTS

Comment: @Max it wouldn't be safe if 0 is one of the possible values. In your case 0 is "illegal value"

Comment: @Quentin Didn't realize `std::vector` value initialized. Thank you.

Comment: @Slava Why is it a bad habit?

Comment: There is absolutely now way to check whether something is initialized or not. It is a programmers responsibility to ensure that program never tries to access uninitialized values. So to make things explicit you can add default constructor for `Atom `

Comment: @NutCracker because it grows from using constants as preprocessor macro and there is a unofficial rule to use preprocessor macro all uppercase. Now constants are not macro anymore and it is better not to make them all uppercase exactly for the same reason - to avoid collision with macro

Comment: You are storing objects, not pointer to objects, so you will always have an object.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks a lot, I'd consider this an answer and accept, if you post it.
Everyone who suggests something that includes changing the class: I can't do that, because the class is auto created by ROS and I'm not supposed to change it's header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to use `pol == 0` should be fine, provided that `pol == 0` is in fact not a normal state for that object to be in and that you don't try it with an uninitialized instance.

The `std::vector` [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) you are using guaranties that the new elements are [default inserted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/DefaultInsertable). If you are using the default allocator (which you are) then that performs [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) of those new elements. Since `Atom` is a class type with a default constructor that is neither user-provided nor deleted, then your instance of `Atom` are [zero initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization). That means each of `Atom`'s members' value is initialized to zero.

Beware that this is something `std::vector` does. You need your `Atom`s to be initialized to zero for this approach to work. If you tried the following, it would be undefined behavior. The `Atom` members are not initialized, much less guaranteed to be zero :

```
int main()
{
    Atom a;
    std::cout << (a.pol == 0); // <- Not okay
}
```

You can force value initialization by adding `{}` though :

```
int main()
{
    Atom a{};
    std::cout << (a.pol == 0); // <- Okay now
}
```

Edit : Accidentally used the same code sample for both examples.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to check whether an object has been initialised. That said, elements of `std::vector` are always initialised, so there is never a need to check either.

It seems that you want to represent an "unassigned" object. The standard library has a template for you: `std::optional`. If you create a vector optional objects, those objects, when value-initialized, will be in "unassigned" state.

> EDIT: pol will always be either -1 or 1 after I assigned an object. So is it safe to check Atom.pol==0?

Yes, that would be safe, since the constructor that you use initialises the elments using a value initialised argument.

If you can assume that some states of the object are "not valid", then you don't necessarily need to use `std::optional`. If the value initialised state is such invalid state, then you don't need to add a default constructor to the class either. Just like a value initialised pointer compares equal to `nullptr`, so too the integer members of the value initialised `Atom` compare equal to 0.

> but I assume that it's not guaranteed to be 0, right?!

It is guaranteed to be 0.

Comment: `std::optional` is available from C++17 on. For previous versions of the language, the OP should resort to `boost::optional`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to change the signature of `vec` to,

`vector<vector<Atom*>> vec=vector<vector<Atom*>>(5,vector<Atom*>(5));`

Then you can do the null ptr check to see if a given element has been initialized. This does add some complexity though, as you have to handle the memory allocation yourself.

Comment: It is better to use `std::unique_ptr` rather than a raw pointer in this case

Answer (score 1):

If you want to initialize the members of `Atom` to specific values and check if they are initialized, you can do this.

```
vector<vector<Atom>> vec=vector<vector<Atom>>(5,vector<Atom>(5, {1, 2, 3}));
```

This initializes `x, y, pol` to `1, 2` and `3` respectively.

Minimal Example:

```
int main() {

    using std::cout;
    using std::vector;

    vector<vector<Atom>> vec=vector<vector<Atom>>(5,vector<Atom>(5, {1, 2, 3}));
    cout<<((vec[0][0]).x == 1) << "\n"; 
    cout<<((vec[0][0]).y == 2)  << "\n";
    cout<<((vec[0][0]).pol == 3)  << "\n";

    cout<<((vec[0][0]).x == -1) << "\n"; 
    cout<<((vec[0][0]).y == -1)  << "\n";
    cout<<((vec[0][0]).pol == -1)  << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

See **[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5xKcgJv7MiFbLsxD)**